# How to place html inputs into grid at its proper place automatic or manual via js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Into grid-columns, say 20 html inputs of different data types as and when user inputs data.   Say grid-container with div elements in correct location for output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you mean...

To display the elements wherever you want inside a grid when the user types something in real-time you can go with this approach:

1 - Directly in HTML :

You can use the "oninput" property of the GlobalEventHandlers

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput

...together with the value of each input :

Let's say we have: (USER INPUT)

```
 <input type="text" 
    id="userName" 

    <!-- ADD THIS -->

    oninput="nameOutput.value = userName.value"/>


which corresponds to : (USER OUTPUT)

<input id="nameOutput">
```

...make sure you use ids to relate both input fields.

this way you obtain simply the value of the input in real-time...

2 - Using a JS function :

then if you assign a JavaScript function to "oninput", you can use :

** innerHTML  : to change content

and

** classList.add() : to style the output however you like

```
 >>> here is where you can place any element inside a new position on a grid
```

So first you create a class describing this new position or whatever you like in CSS :

let's say we have a 20x20 grid and this element was positioned in the first column and the first row:

### CSS

```
.showNameOutput {
  grid-column: 5/6;
    grid-row: 1/2;

  background-color: blue; /* or whatever */
}
```

---

this changes its position in the grid

and then you can add this class to the element previously selected

### JS

```
const nameOutput = document.querySelector('.nameOutput'); // the the output HTML element has this class

function myFunction() {
  nameOutput.classList.add('showNameOutput'); // we're adding new properties to that element
}
```

---

the function will execute whenever the user types anything in the input, so it will "move" the output element

---

....see the example below, it might help...I just added a couple of things :

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_oninput

first you create a class that will change some CSS property :

```
<style>
.change {
    color: red;
    }
</style>


<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>
```

then you asign the function to oninput :

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

and create the function where you use that class :

```
<script>

function myFunction() {
  //extract the value from the DOM input :
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value; 
    // use of innerHTML :
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
    // use of classList.add('yourClass') to make CSS changes:
  element.classList.add('change'); // in this case we just change the color as you can see
}

</script>
```

---

---

- Displaying all at once :

In this case the values may be entered with some kind of form and a submit button if you like...

Then you can use an array to store those values and then display them all together at once when the user clicks the button using any logic you prefer... you can use these properties too.

I hope this helps...

Comment: File Link: https://sureshs2022.w3spaces.com/imagioprojectbox/animehomepage.html or /..../employ.html....this file is about grid columns where user input data can't be put into respective positions...I did few things from above answer like getting all common user inputs...great stuff, suggestions and changes to written codes are welcome